# How to assign zero(0) when the avg of a particular field is null in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.1

I have two tables:

Table `user_ratings`

```
id  home_info_id  ratings
1   1             3.5 
2   2             3.5
3   1             4
4   1             5
5   1             2
6   2             1
7   2             4
```

Table `home_info`:

```
id  home_name 
1   my_home
2   ur_home
3   his_home
```

As you can see 'my_home' and 'ur_home' has ratings but 'his_home' is not rated yet. I am calculating the avg of all homes, so I am getting avg of only two homes, i.e. 'my_home' and 'ur_home', as I said 'his_home' is not rated yet, so I am not getting 'his_home' in my query below. I want all the names of homes which are not rated yet. Here is my query:

```
select u.home_info_id
     , avg(u.ratings)
     , h.home_name
from user_ratings u
   , home_info h 
where h.id = u.home_info_id
group by u.home_info_id
       , h.home_name;
```

The output is something like this:

```
home_info_id  ratings  home_name 
1             4.83     my_home     
2             2.83     ur_home
```

But I want something like this:

```
 home_info_id  ratings  home_name 
 1             4.83     my_home     
 2             2.83     ur_home
 3             0        his_home
```

Comment: Why the MySQL tag? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: query is same for all, If i get some idea with mysql query i will implement in postgresql

Comment: Removed sql and mysql tags now please upvote my downvoted question please, now it has enough info.:-(

Comment: `user_review` or `user_ratings`? Please make the question consistent.

Comment: Question is understood by answerer and i got answer sir @ErwinBrandstetter

Comment: @arunaangadi: This is a public site. Questions are supposed to be useful to the general public. It's not a service to write queries for you. Please fix the question.

Comment: Fixed mr.@ErwinBrandstetter by the way I didnt mean to be public and private the main intension i think to be gain knowledge nobody is writing queries for me, I am here to acquire knowledge from the persons who wish to share. Thank you for the catching mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` with `LEFT JOIN` (instead of implicit `INNER JOIN`):

```
select h.id
     , coalesce(avg(u.ratings), 0)
     , h.home_name
from home_info h 
left join user_review u on h.id = u.home_info_id
group by h.id
       , h.home_name
```

Comment: Well I am getting field names for home_name and rating but home_info id blank

Comment: @aruna angadi: Well, you can't get the result you are writing about, if you use `LEFT JOIN` as it leaves all records from `home_info` (rated `1`, `2` and unrated `3`).

Comment: So i will not get the hall_info_id field for unrated home??

Comment: @aruna angadi: Well, just retrieve `home_info.id` instead of `user_review.home_info_id`.

Comment: Many thanks....I am upvoting you, Sir please tell to upvote mine too somebody downvoted my question. thank you soo much

Comment: Why do you chose to select h.id and h.home_name, but group by u.home_info_id  and h.home_name?

Comment: @jarlh: Well, because I _forgot_ to change `u.home_info_id` to `h.id` in the `GROUP BY` clause)

Comment: That was the problem @notulysses thanks for the help.. somebody please solve my this question please I am using codeigniter to take ip addresses but I am not getting ip address, getting as 0.0.0.0, nobody answered me please check out my quesion. link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29367137/codeigniter-ci-sessions-table-storing-ip-address-as-0-0-0-0-why-even-when-hoste

Comment: @notulysses To be precise :  use an order by clause for your select ie `order by h.id`

Answer (score 1):

When scanning the whole table or most of it, it is cheaper to aggregate *before* you join:

```
SELECT h.id, h.home_name
     , COALESCE(u.avg_rating, 0) AS avg_rating
FROM   home_info h
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT home_info_id AS id, avg(ratings) AS avg_rating
   FROM   user_review
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) u USING (id);
```

Test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

- [How to make a SELECT query in Hibernate includes Subquery COUNT(*)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853144/how-to-make-a-select-query-in-hibernate-includes-subquery-count/9853422#9853422)
- [Aggregate a single column in query with many columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018237/aggregate-a-single-column-in-query-with-many-columns/16023336#16023336)